Cplex showing value of decision variables as 0
So I am solving a transportation optimization model with some changes on my own. The model runs successfully but when I see the values of the decision variables it showing me a 3D array with all values as 0.
.mod file
int m = ...;
int n = ...;
int o = ...;

range I = 1..m;
range J = 1..n;
range K = 1..o;

float d[I][J] = ...;
float s[I] = ...;
float f = ...;
float v = ...;
float q = ...;
float u[I][J][K];

dvar float x[I][J][K];
dvar int y[I][J][K];

float data[1..9][1..261] = ...;

minimize sum(i in I, j in J, k in K) f*y[i][j][k] + sum(i in I, j in J, k in K) v*d[i][j]*y[i][j][k];

subject to {
  Constraint1: forall(j in J, k in K) sum(i in I) x[i][j][k] == sum(i in I) u[i][j][k];
  
  Constraint2: forall(i in I) sum(j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] <= s[i];
  
  Constraint3: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] <= q*y[i][j][k];
  
  Constraint4: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] >= 0;
  Constraint5: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) y[i][j][k] >= 0;
}

execute {
  
    for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <= 261; j++) {
                // Calculate the row index based on k and i
                var row = (k - 1) * 3 + i; // 3 rows per k
                u[i][j][k] = data[row][j]; // Offset by 1 for customer index
            }
        }
    }
}

.dat file
m = 3;
n = 261;
o = 3;

SheetConnection Sheet ("ProjectData.xlsx");
d from SheetRead (Sheet, "CPLEX! C6:JC8");
s from SheetRead (Sheet, "Data! C3:C5");
f from SheetRead (Sheet, "Data! B16");
v from SheetRead (Sheet, "Data! B17");
q from SheetRead (Sheet, "Data! B18");
data from SheetRead (Sheet, "CPLEX! C16:JC24");

I have checked the values of all parameters to see if the value is correct and that is coming out to be the case. CPLEX is not giving me any reason as well why my model will not run. I am on student CPLEX version if it helps.

Hi, without the Excel file nobody can reproduce your issue. Plus, why do you say your model could not run ? According to me , cplex found a solution and that  solution is full o 0s

I think that the issue could be that you wrote
float u[I][J][K];

which means all u are 0
int m = 3;
int n = 261;
int o = 3;

range I = 1..m;
range J = 1..n;
range K = 1..o;

float d[i in I][j in J] = rand(10);
float s[i in I] = rand(10)+200000;
float f = 2;
float v = 3;
float q = 8000;
float u[i in I][j in J][k in K]=rand(10);

dvar float x[I][J][K];
dvar int y[I][J][K];

float data[i in 1..9][j in 1..261] = rand(10);

minimize sum(i in I, j in J, k in K) f*y[i][j][k] + sum(i in I, j in J, k in K) v*d[i][j]*y[i][j][k];

subject to {
  Constraint1: forall(j in J, k in K) sum(i in I) x[i][j][k] == sum(i in I) u[i][j][k];
  
  Constraint2: forall(i in I) sum(j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] <= s[i];
  
  Constraint3: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] <= q*y[i][j][k];
  
  Constraint4: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) x[i][j][k] >= 0;
  Constraint5: forall(i in I, j in J, k in K) y[i][j][k] >= 0;
}

execute {
  
    for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <= 261; j++) {
                // Calculate the row index based on k and i
                var row = (k - 1) * 3 + i; // 3 rows per k
                u[i][j][k] = data[row][j]; // Offset by 1 for customer index
            }
        }
    }
}  

gives a non null solution

Hi, your solution does work and the values of u are also the same though I don't understand the logic behind this. Can you tell me why this worked and others did not? I though that I might get random values for u in each iteration instead of the actual data but that is not the case as well.
